# Retaining resources after terraform destroy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'd like to retain CloudWatch logs after I spin down a bunch of resources created using terraform - which includes the CloudWatch log group. Is there a way to tell `terraform destroy` to spare some resources?

I suppose I could manually remove CloudWatch resources from tfstate before calling destroy, doesn't seem like the right approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a [meta-argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html) called lifecycle for that.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "MyPreciousBucket" {
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: This is NOT a solution to @RaGe's question. `prevent_destroy` only makes an entire `destroy` operation fail if set to `true` on a resource. It doesn't answer OP's issue which is about being able to undertake a `destroy` operation on the current terraform configuration while ensuring the given resource will exceptionally not be destroyed. I.e. destroying every resource in the config except the one in question. Your idea only prevents us from being able to `terraform destroy`, which is completely useless in the context of OP's post.

Comment: The issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3874) by the way. And after 300 upvotes and 7 years waiting, Hashicorp still hasn't done anything to address this...

Answer (score 1):

In cloudformation, there is an option `retain` [DeletionPolicy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html)

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Resources" : {
    "myS3Bucket" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "DeletionPolicy" : "Retain"
    }
  }
}
```

But in terraform, I didn't find this type of [lifecycle](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#lifecycle)

You can search in [terraform issue list](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20retain%20lifecycle) or raise a new ticket to follow this issue.