# Terraform: how to not delete resource during destroy?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

What I need is terraform analog for CloudFormation's `DeletionPolicy: Retain`.

The resource should be left as is during `terraform destroy`, that's all.

`prevent_destroy` does not fit because the whole environment going to be deleted during terraform destroy

`ignore_changes` does not fit because there's no parameter's change.

How can I do it?

Comment: I have answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172833/retaining-resources-after-terraform-destroy/69976109#69976109

Comment: @SergeyBelash prevent_destroy does not fit, see above.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could break down the destroy to a set of tasks

1. Use [`terraform state rm`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/rm.html), to remove resources/modules you want to retain, from your state. Now they are no longer tracked by terraform.
2. Remove these resources/modules, from your `.tf` files
3. Run `terraform plan`. You should see that there are no changes to be applied. This is to ensure that the selected resources have been safely removed from your terraform state files and terraform code.
4. Run `terraform destroy`. This should destroy all other resources.